# Center HTML element in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to embed a Power BI report to my website in Wordpress using the HTML tool. Since when using the embedding version of the report of Power Bi, a button to share the report appears (and it really can't in this case), I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447297/remove-share-bar-from-power-bi-public-embed) on how to "cut" the HTML element so that the down part wouldn't appear. I'm saying this just to explain why maybe the code down can look more complicated than needed. My problem now is that I'm trying to center this element on the page, but I don't know why I can't make it work in all PCs, since in mine it appears centered but in others that I tried it didn't.
This is the code that I have until now

```
<div id="content">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="aligncenter">
<div style="height:500px;width:400px">
   <iframe width="600" height="400" src="LinkOfReport" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; clip:rect(0px,1000px,344px,0px);
           ; zoom:162%;allowFullScreen=" true=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

I don't understand much of HTML or CSS so if someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Your code snippet contains several typos like unclosed quotation marks. For instance, the inline `style` tag on the line 4 has a missing `"`, and the `iframe` tag also has `"` closing mismatch. I would start there. Otherwise, "not understanding much of HTML/CSS" unfortunately wouldn't help you too much either.

Comment: @Bumhan Yu Already changed it and it was not the problem. I already did a lot of research and didn't find any solution that worked. Do you have any idea of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to understand what was happening. Basically, I copied part of the code from the question I mentioned in the post, since I needed to crop the HTML element. I understood that a part of it was forcing the element to start more to the left (the part of `<div style="height:500px;width:400px">`) and another one to keep the element fixed in the same place, independently of the size of the window (`position: absolute`)

I also changed the type of clip I was using, since from what I read, [clip property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) is exclusive to absolutely positioned elements. So now I'm using clip-path property.

Summing up, this is my final code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="aligncenter">
   <iframe width="600" height="400" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjE4ZDExNGQtNjgwYS00OTUwLTkzYjYtNjM1YjNjMGJkMjU4IiwidCI6ImU0YmQ2OWZmLWU2ZjctNGMyZS1iMjQ3LTQxYjU0YmEyNDkwZSIsImMiOjh9&amp;pageName=ReportSection" frameborder="0" style="clip-path: inset(0 0 38px 0); zoom:162%"> </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope these explanations help anyone that is trying to start in HTML and CSS